# Prove that this series converges (originally from information theory)

Tags: sequences-and-series, information-theory

Suppose the positive sequence $p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots$ satisfies $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty p_i=1$. Prove that if $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty p_i \log i$ converges, then so does $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty p_i \log \frac1{p_i}$.

I found this problem in an information theory textbook (problem 2.45 from Elements of Information Theory by Cover and Thomas), but the problem can be formulated as a pure math problem. If you're curious, the original problem is: Show that for a discrete random variable $X\in \{1,2,\ldots\}$, if $\mathbb E\left[\log X\right]<\infty $, then $H(X)<\infty$. ($H(X)$ is the entropy of random variable $X$.)

Comment: Are the $p_i$ positive?

Comment: Yes, fixed. Thanks

Comment: check out the paper "A note of the summability of the entropy series" by J. Keilson, 1971. In particular, Theorem 1.

Comment: A.D. Wyner, "An upper bound on the entropy series", Corollary to Theorem 2: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995872903658